In the Genesis Config, what does the `patch` key do?
When creating a genesis config, we have the ability to add a genesis.runtimeGenesis.patch.
What is the main purpose of this patch and why would I use this rather than directly setting the runtimeGenesis?
Some docs: https://docs.rs/sp-genesis-builder/latest/sp_genesis_builder/

The runtime may provide a number of partial predefined RuntimeGenesisConfig configurations in the form of patches which shall be applied on top of the default RuntimeGenesisConfig. The patch is a JSON blob, which essentially comprises the list of key-value pairs that are to be customized in the default runtime genesis config. These predefined configurations are referred to as presets.


The more relevant doc describing the chain spec format is here:
https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/sc_chain_spec/index.html#
The RuntimeGenesisConfig within a chain-spec can be provided in two formats - full json representation of RuntimeGenesisConfig struct, and patch representation applied to the default value of RuntimeGenesisConfig.
The main purpose of genesis config patch:

minimize the maintenance effort when RuntimeGenesisConfig is changed in future (e.g. new pallets added to runtime or pallet's genesis config changed),
increase readability - it only contains relevant fields,
allows to apply numerous changes in distinct domains (e.g. for zombienet).

Patch is intended for development/testing configurations.
(link to relevant discussion: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/62#issuecomment-1763992444)

what happens when both a config and patch are included in the same file?

I've never tried this scenario. By intention/design they are exclusive, and deserialization shall fail at some point (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/b78d7955e280309dc7cbd6b0b40819e942dfc597/substrate/client/chain-spec/src/chain_spec.rs#L44), unless some serde directives (which were heavily used in chain-spec implementation) will prevent it. I'd suggest opening issue if that is the case.
